# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error with Laravel and React

Tags: laravel, reactjs, get, cross-domain

I am sending a request from my react app `localhost:8080` to my lumen api `localhost:8000` to retrieve json data.

This is my `routes.php` in lumen: `$app->get('list', 'ArticleController@listAll');`

And this is my `ArticleController.php` in lumen:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Article as Article;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function listAll(){
        $articles = Article::all();

        return response()
            ->json($articles)
            ->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));

    }
}
```

Because I get that error for cross domain fetch, I am trying to use jsonp, but for some reason it's still not working.

This is my code in React:

```
componentWillMount(){

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/list?callback=asdf', {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm very new to this kind of stuff.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your API server should return correct CORS headers, to allow using it from other domains.

You have two options to solve this:

1. Add correct CORS in your API responses, there is ready to use solutions like this one https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors or you can even make your own https://gist.github.com/danharper/06d2386f0b826b669552
2. Use proxy that will add CORS headers (it is possible to add CORS headers to responses using webserver configuration)
3. Use JSONP

About JSONP - it is pretty valid option, and it will work...

But in your case it is not working, because `fetch` - is not the way you can use it.

JSONP is about creating script tag with your request url, and waiting for global callback specified in url to be called when script is loaded([What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)). You need to implement it on your own, or better - use libraries implementing it (for example jQuery)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, just one more question though. Would it be bad to use JSONP if the clients were random strangers? Like If i wanted to make a reddit clone where I have a server for all the json data and the cleint side gets all the data from the server by JSONP, will it be safe to use JSONP on my part?

Comment: Also with JSONP, you can only use the `GET` request and not `PUT` right?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to send requests other than `GET` via `JSONP`.

Comment: There is few security concerns associated with JSONP, you should be aware of: at first, via `JSONP` server can send any JS response, not only JSON - so clients need to trust api provider; second - it can be subject to cross-site request forgery attacks. In general - better use CORS headers.

Comment: Hey, I just have one more problem. I used the cors header and I successfully got a response, but my response looks like this, http://i.imgur.com/NgSUZBA.png and I have no idea where my returned json is. Could you help me navigate to the location of my data?

Comment: it would be something like: `fetch('....').then(r=>r.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your help.